# Passing table name as parameter to model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm still figuring out the MVC approach and I have a question regarding the proper usage of models in Codeigniter.

I have this method in my model:

```
function select_user($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

This fetches a record by ID from the `users` table. That's all good, but now I have to do the same with a different table. Is there any objection (in Codeigniter or MVC in general) to expanding the method above so that the table name is passed as a parameter, so as to make it reusable for any table?

Something like this is what I had in mind:

```
function select_by_id($id,$tbl)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get($tbl);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

It's assumed that each table has a unique `ID` column. My goal is to not have to write 10 different methods that do essentially the same thing for 10 different DB tables.

Comment: Passing in the table like that should work - are you having problems with it?

Comment: No, it works. My only question is whether it breaks some sort of MVC/Codeigniter convention, or if it has any consequences I haven't foreseen.

Comment: No, its perfectly fine to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing is completely right.